# joomla: how do i load a module content in more than one loadposition

Tags: module, joomla

I'm developing a Joomla module and I'm trying to display this module's content in more than one position for example, "user10" and "user11".

I tried to separate positions using "," and by ";" but it didn't work.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

To do that :

. Create a copy of the module and assign it to 2 different module positions

or

Create 2 module positions with the same name on the 2 different places

There's no otherway

Comment: Thank you Ahmed
but unfortunately I can't use this two solutions.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can create multiple instance of Modules from Module Manager.

Go to new and select the module which you want to show.

Then assign them different position.